# Oracle SQL sysdate with time

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

I am using Oracle SQL.  I'm trying to use sysdate with time to give the me query result.  I have placed a time in the where clause, but I need it to be automatic and using the sysdate and converting to local time is the correct way.  Any thoughts?

```
SELECT RESOURCE, AVG(SALES) AS SALES
FROM Z_HOURLY_RESOURCE
WHERE DATE_TIME_START BETWEEN to_date(to_char(FROM_TZ( CAST( (to_date('2018-08-02T05:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss') )AS TIMESTAMP ), 'America/Los_Angeles') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss')
  AND to_date(to_char(FROM_TZ( CAST( (to_date('2018-08-02T13:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss')+1) AS TIMESTAMP ), 'America/Los_Angeles') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: What data type is `DATE_TIME_START` - sounds like a date or timestamp representing a UTC time, is that right? If you want the query to be based on the current date, what time range (local - so what time zone; or UTC) do you want? Sample data and expected results might also be helpful - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: DATE_TIME_START IS A TIMESTAMP(6).  I want the time range to be local from 5am to 1pm local time on Los Angeles Time.

Comment: So that column has values which represent the time in LA? Referring to local time and a specific time zone is slightly confusing. Is the DB server also on LA time?

Comment: No, the server is in France which is why the sysdate is based on UTC.  So I need to convert the date and time to LA time, but with the time range.  The columns specified in my questions have values if I can correct the date format i'm trying to achieve.  If the I run the code I exampled it runs fine with results.

Comment: Why would the fact, that the server is in France, indicate the `sysdate` to return values in UTC? `sysdate` depends on the OS time and time zone, which in France would usually be CET/CEST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's slightly hard to work out quite what you need without sample data, but it sounds like you want to convert the time range 05:00 to 13:00 in your local session time zone (e.g. LA) to UTC to compare with the UTC-based timestamps in your table.

You can do that with:

```
WHERE DATE_TIME_START >= sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 5/24 as timestamp with time zone))
  AND DATE_TIME_START <  sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 13/24 as timestamp with time zone))
```

I've used `>=` and `<` rather than `between` on the assumption you really want *up to* 13:00, which is usually the case for time ranges. If you do want to include data form exactly 13:00:00 then change that `<` to `<=`, or go back to `between`.

TO explain what that is doing a but: `current_date` gives you the date/time in your session time zone. Truncating that sets the time to midnight (by default), so you can then add either 5 or 13 hours to get the times you want. That is still a date, so you can cast to timestamp with time zone so it represents that time in your session time zone again. You can then use `sys_extract_utc()` to get the UTC-equivalent timestamp.

To demonstrate those steps:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1 TZH:TZM';

select sysdate as a,
  current_date as b,
  trunc(current_date) as c,
  trunc(current_date) + 5/24 as d,
  cast(trunc(current_date) + 5/24 as timestamp with time zone) as e,
  sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 5/24 as timestamp with time zone)) as f
from dual
union all
select sysdate as a,
  current_date as b,
  trunc(current_date) as c,
  trunc(current_date) + 13/24 as d,
  cast(trunc(current_date) + 13/24 as timestamp with time zone) as e,
  sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 13/24 as timestamp with time zone)) as f
from dual;

A                   B                   C                   D                   E                            F                    
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------
2018-08-02 18:56:23 2018-08-02 10:56:23 2018-08-02 00:00:00 2018-08-02 05:00:00 2018-08-02 05:00:00.0 -07:00 2018-08-02 12:00:00.0
2018-08-02 18:56:23 2018-08-02 10:56:23 2018-08-02 00:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00 2018-08-02 13:00:00.0 -07:00 2018-08-02 20:00:00.0
```

Comment: That did it!!! Thanks Alex for your prompt responses and great detail of demostration.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Alex, i ran into an issue while doing a UNION ALL.  I have 3 shifts I need to pull based on time range - 5am-1pm, 1pm-9pm, 9pm-5am next day.  The current_date and format of +5/24 or +13/24 and using it for the other shifts throws off the data incorrectly?  Any suggestions?

Comment: 13/24 to 21/24 shouldn't be a problem, going over midnight is only slightly more complicated. I'm not sure what you mean about a union though. If you want all three shifts in one query then use one query and include the range in the group-by. You might need to ask a new question explaining your new issue though.

Comment: To cope with going over midnight, you probably just need to use `(24+5)/24`, to get to 5 A.M. next day. A more tricky issue might be, if you still want to show something, when current time is between midnight and 5 A.M., as with the above queries, you will be trying to show data for shifts, that have not yet started. You might address it by subtracting `5/24` from `current_date` before you apply `trunc` to it.

Comment: Thanks both.  +05/24 - +13/24 , +13/24 - +21/24, AND +21/24 - CURRENT_DATE+1 + 05/24

Comment: This did the trick.  Thanks All.  WHERE DATE_TIME_START >= sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date) + 19/24 as timestamp with time zone))
AND DATE_TIME_START <  sys_extract_utc(cast(trunc(current_date+1) + 5/24 as timestamp with time zone))

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have to cast a `TIMESTAMP` to a `CHAR` and then back again to a `TIMESTAMP`.

Assuming `DATE_TIME_START` is a `TIMESTAMP` and times are given in UTC you can make it simpler. When Oracle compares `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values then comparison are always done automatically at UTC time value. Your condition would be like this.

```
SELECT RESOURCE, AVG(SALES) AS SALES
FROM Z_HOURLY_RESOURCE
WHERE FROM_TZ(DATE_TIME_START, 'UTC') 
   BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-08-02T05:00:00 America/Los_Angeles', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss TZR')
       AND TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-08-02T13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss TZR')
```

However, due to function `FROM_TZ(DATE_TIME_START, 'UTC')` the performance might not be the best, it depends on your data.

If you need condition based on current time it would be like this:

```
SELECT RESOURCE, AVG(SALES) AS SALES
FROM Z_HOURLY_RESOURCE
WHERE FROM_TZ(DATE_TIME_START, 'UTC') 
   BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) 
       AND TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Above query just illustrate time zone handling. You don't have to consider time zone of `SYSTIMESTAMP`, comparison will work in any case.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried.  The query ran a lot quicker with the last query.  But I have a time range for 3 shifts, 5am-1pm, 1pm-9pm, 9pm-5am next day.  Would this work either way?

Comment: Of course, you can use `BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) AND TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '1 05:00' DAY TO MINUTE`